# Word VBA script compiles without error but doesn't work

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote the VBA macro below for the purpose of reinforcing some Word 2010 style specifications that tend to unravel during my report authoring process.  The macro compiles without error, but when I run it on a test report in which all formatting but the style name assignments have been removed, nothing happens at all.

```
Sub ntsReportFormatting()

    Dim ntsReportDoc As Word.Document

    Dim ntsNormal As Style
    Dim ntsTOC1 As Style
    Dim ntsTOC2 As Style
    Dim ntsTOC3 As Style

    Set ntsReportDoc = ActiveDocument

    Set ntsNormal = ntsReportDoc.Styles("Normal")
    With ntsNormal
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0.5
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0.6
    End With

    Set ntsTOC1 = ntsReportDoc.Styles("TOC 1")
    With ntsTOC1
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Bold = True
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0.6
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0.6
    End With

    Set ntsTOC2 = ntsReportDoc.Styles("TOC 2")
    With ntsTOC2
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0.17
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0.6
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0.6
        .NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = True
    End With

    Set ntsTOC3 = ntsReportDoc.Styles("TOC 3")
    With ntsTOC3
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0.33
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0.6
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0.6
        .NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = True
    End With

End Sub
```

I've consulted Lynda.com, the MSDN documentation, Youtube and Google and I haven't been able to find a clear solution.

Comment: Try substituting the WdBuiltinStyle enum values for the literal string values - wdStyleNormal instead of "Normal", for example - and see if that makes a difference. You can find the list in the VBA object browser (F2) or Intellisense should provide it if you type WdBuiltinStyle. (but note that I'm giving you this from memory so I might be making typos!)

Comment: It might be that the `Style` does update but it did not update in the Document text. It also worked fine for me, except for the TOC styles, which I do not have assigned in my Style Set.

Answer (score 0):

I cant confirm a problem, macro works properly, changing the style according to defined parameters

Comment: That's actually really helpful!  It worked for someone!  Maybe there's a box I need to check or uncheck somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The problem i had was that it updated the style but it did not update the document text.

What I did is run a `Loop` after you have reset your `Styles`.

Add this after your last Style Editing Statement.

```
For p = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(p).Range.Select

    ParaStyle = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(p).Range.style

    Selection.Range.style = ParaStyle

Next
```

I'm not sure if there is another way do this.

Answer (score 0):

It also worked fine for me, but based on Jean-Pierre's answer I have to wonder whether direct formatting has been applied to the text. That will over-ride the style formatting so changes to the style won't show up.

There are a set of commands that remove various types of formatting from the current Selection. They all start with the term "Clear".

I selected a paragraph and applied a different font to it, for example. Changing the style didn't show up until I first did this:

```
ntsReportDoc.Select
Selection.ClearCharacterDirectFormatting
```

But you have to be aware that this kind of thing could also remove italics, etc. if they haven't been applied using a style.